Do individual rights supersede the raison d'état?
The question is motivated by threads Was Nixon's "when the President does it, that means that it is not illegal" technically correct? and Who originated the idea that the purpose of government is to protect its citizens?. I used to think that in modern western democracies individual rights are inviolable, even in the name of national interests (raison d'état), and that the watershed moment for the choice between the supremacy of the two was the Dreyfus affair (although the lack of evidence for his conviction was understood quite early, it was maintained for years in the name of the reasons of state.) However, the accepted answer to the first thread cited above, and the recent supreme court decision gave me some doubts.
In which  countries can a government/president violate individual rights (e.g., imprison or execute an innocent person) in the interests of state/nation? Are there any states, where a possibility or illegality of such an action is explicitly inscribed in the law/constitution? I mean mostly western states, but other examples are welcome, if not too trivial (ok, dictatorships, and communist/fascist regimes routinely violate individual rights.)
Related: Anwar al-Awlaki, Killing of Abdulrahman al-Awlaki

When you say "violate individual rights", do you solely mean life and liberty, as in your example, or do you mean any fundamental right?

@Cadence good point. I suggest limiting it to life and liberty or other cases where the violation can be easily proven/evident. Also, what rights are included in fundamental rights varies from place to place

go back 4 years, and look for a nation, which did NOT violate such a right. The answer is all of them can violate whatever they find necessary right on the spot.

If internment counts as "violating individual rights", then the list could be quite long, and would include the US and UK, among many others.

@dEmigOd de facto yes - they surely do. But do they do it legally or do they violate their own laws?

@StackExchangeSupportsIsrael yes, as per my earlier comment - where it is actually illegal.

TBH the Trump example and the other ones aren't that closely related. SCOTUS didn't decide that Trump can kill whomever he wants in office. And getting killed in a warzone basically (al-Awlakis), is not that uncommon, nor generally illegal for some classes. You may quibble around the def of 'enemy combatant' etc.

FWTW/FYI, regarding the Trump case https://youtu.be/Dc4_RFeKaz4?t=97 And more generally relevant, many Western countries have moved away from the (US-style) principle that prosecution is a monolithic power of the executive branch. There was a Q here about that...

I don't think I can make a single-character change, so can the next person to edit this change the word in the title to supersede? Fun fact: "supersede" is the only word in the English language that ends in -sede. There are three common ones that end in -ceed: exceed, proceed, succeed. All others end in -cede. Thus endeth the English lesson for the day.

@shoover Thanks, this is interesting. From what Google says - supercede and supersede both exist, but mean somewhat different things.


In which countries can a government/president violate individual
rights (e.g., imprison or execute an innocent person) in the interests
of state/nation? Are there any states, where a possibility or
illegality of such an action is explicitly inscribed in the
law/constitution?

This is an unhelpful way to frame the question.
In U.S. law, for example, almost no individual rights are absolute.
Your right to free exercise of religion ends when you decide you want to involuntarily use him as a human sacrifice in your religious ritual. Your right to free speech doesn't allow you to defraud someone in the sale of a home. Your right to not be executed without due process doesn't extend to military force authorized by Congress and conducted pursuant the rules of engagement set by the chain of authority from the President on down (this is the  Anwar al-Awlaki, case). Your right not to be deprived of property without just compensation doesn't extend to things that you aren't allowed to own like slaves or cocaine or nuclear warheads, and doesn't mean that you have a right to be free of taxes on your property. Your right to vote is conditioned on you bothering to show up to the polls or cast a mail-in ballot by election day. Your right to liberty (if you don't violate the law) is subordinate to the government's right to quarantine you to prevent the spread of a deadly disease.
Sometimes the government does things that it isn't supposed to do, because life isn't perfect.
A police officer executes a no knock warrant at the wrong address, which the executing officer may have had no way to know was wrong, and it causes harm or death. You are arrested and detained prior to trial because there is evidence pointing to your guilt of a crime, but you didn't actually do it. The guy driving a postal van didn't get any sleep the night before because his baby was crying all night, doesn't pay attention, and crashes into a pedestrian causing serious harm. A cop loses his temper and beats the shit out of you because you insulted him even though it was illegal to do so.
The law in those cases decides what remedy, if any, you are entitled to when the government screws up.
If you are innocent but prosecuted in good faith based upon plausible evidence, you don't get anything and have to suffer for the good of society. If the postal van crash broke your legal, you are entitled to money damages from the government and the driver. If the cop loses his temper and unlawfully beats you up, you are entitled to compensatory economic damages like medical costs and lost wages, non-economic damages for pain and suffering, punitive damages, interest, court costs, and attorney fees, but you don't have a right to have the bad cop removed from the police force.
Immunity from liability mostly fits in the category of finding an appropriate remedy even if it sometimes means there is no remedy.
Someone has done something wrong, but for public policy reasons, punishing the person who did it is not the remedy that is available. Presidential immunity is a hard pill to swallow, but it makes lots of sense in the case of judicial immunity. If a judge screws up, you can appeal the judge's decision but you can't sue the judge, because the job is challenging enough that all judges make mistakes sometimes and you couldn't find someone willing to serve if they could be sued every time they got a legal issue wrong.
There are diehards, like the late Justice Scalia, who took the position that even if you could unequivocally prove that you were innocent after key deadlines had passed, that if you were sentenced to death in a case where all your legal rights were respected, that you should be executed. Most judges and legal scholars don't agree, but it is a position taken by someone who had a say in thousands of legal decisions that are the absolute law of the land in the U.S. and many judges do agree with him.
Some countries, like Canada, allow parliament to specifically say that they are going to intentionally violate most of your individual rights (there are some exceptions and conditions) notwithstanding the fact that they are protected by its Charter of Rights and Freedoms, so long as parliament is willing to admit that this is what it is doing.
In sum, it is perfectly normal for some individual rights to yield to greater concerns, or to make it illegal for government to do something but to limit what remedies you have if it does. Some countries go further even than that.

Your right to free exercise of religion ends when you decide you want to involuntarily use him as a human sacrifice in your religious ritual. To be pedantic, I am quite sure that it would also end if the human sacrifice were voluntary.

@SJuan76 Of course. There are myriad possible examples, I chose the more likely one of those two.

While I agree with this in principle, I can also see the viewpoint that land taxes mean that ownership of land, as such, doesn't exist in the US and one can only enter into a perpetual lease of land from counties (in which counties cannot revoke most terms of the lease, but can increase the rent).

@wrod No country in the world has every interpreted an individual's right to own property in that manner.

@ohwilleke Interesting, but IMHO lacks specific examples. Could a Dreyfus-like situation  be possible in the US: when a person is kept imprisoned, because admitting the miscarriage of justice could compromise the US security? Or if we take 'Israel hostage dilemma' - would US release dangerous terrorists in order to release its citizens from captivity?

@Morisco "when a person is kept imprisoned, because admitting the miscarriage of justice could compromise the US security?" This is happening right now in the Guantanamo situation and was approved legally in the Padilla and Hamdi cases.

@ohwilleke I didn't know that there are US citizens imprisoned in Guantanamo.

@Morisco Citizenship is besides the point as with a couple of tiny exceptions almost never matters with respect to rights under U.S. law or the authority of the U.S. government. Certainly, Padilla and Hamdi hold that the U.S. war powers extend to U.S. citizens in and outside the territory of the U.S. https://www.americanbar.org/groups/law_students/resources/on-demand/quimbee-hamdi-v-rumsfeld/

@ohwilleke I suggest adding a discussion as an example to the answer. With the minimum background for non-Americans.

@ohwilleke "No country in the world has every interpreted an individual's right to own property in that manner."  Are you sure?  I would think The Crown (in the British sense of the term) may disagree.

@wrod Since when do the British assert that property cannot be taxed?

@ohwilleke they can be.  But that right derives from the lords' rights to charge rent.  So you can't say that the concept I suggested is novel.  It's more outdated than novel.

@wrod The lord's interest in land came with obligations to provide services to the next lord up the chain and wasn't alienable.

There are political philosophies which hold that every single human right is sacred, and that a government may not violate them for any reason. And then there are political philosophies which hold that in practice, rights can come into conflict with each other, and that governments (and others) must balance them.
If the latter premise is accepted, there is the question of balancing rules -- it is 'the greatest good for the greatest number,' or a bias towards inaction if any action would harm somebody, or some ranking of rights against each other (person A's right to live vs. person B's right to property, for instance).
That debate is not resolved. See

Trolley Problem
The passing and then abolition of the German Luftsicherheitsgesetz.
volonté générale


Coventry and ULTRA may not be the best example, as the location of the bombing raid in question was not known in advance.

@SteveMelnikoff, Ultra without Coventry might make the point, but the other three bullet points are probably enough.

re: "There are political philosophies which hold that every single human right is sacred"  Philosophies, in themselves, do not amount to actions.  They can, of course, inform actions, but even inaction, in the face of one's philosophy not comporting with the events, results in one affecting outcomes contrary to one's philosophy.  There is also, of course, the philosophy that actions speak louder than words.

I'll answer this question from a libertarian point of view.
All modern governments are coersion based, so they inheritely violate your individual rights by coersing you into participating and coercing you to finance it. The only modern voluntary governments, for example Prospera, are within authonomous zone of larger states, for example Honduras.
For a libertarian, a government is a service like any other, and needs to be provided freely by businesses in a market without any special privilege. The same laws that apply to a bakery would apply to your house and to the government.
So in order for a government to not violate individual rights, they would need the following:

Legitimate territory adquisition, for example exploration or trade with legitimaly adquired funds. Conquest is a violation of the individual rights of the previous owners.
Respect all contracts, formal or informal, made with the residents. Fraud is a violation of individual rights.
Restrain from using violence against any peaceful resident. Violence can be used against aggressors (people that initiate violence or coersion) to prevent the continuation of the aggression and to restitute the victims if damages were caused.
Arbitrary rules can be applied to the region, however, response to violations of arbitrary rules are limited to what was mutually agreed on the contracts, or through expulsion. Any other form of violence or coersion to enforce an arbitrary rule is a violation of individual rights.

No modern government fulfil these requirements perfectly, although some, like the aformentioned Prospera, gets sort of close. A government which does not violate individual rights would look very similar to how things are done in condos, and Prospera is the closest government to a condo that we have in the world at the moment.
If you do some mental gymnastic and ignore the legitimacy issue, since most people dont consider practical to focus on ancient crimes, you could treat modern governments as either being the property of

The monarch or dictator in their respective models
The people, in the case of democracies
Or a voluntary aliance of smaller governments in the case of some republics

In democracies, the people are like shareholders of a private government and their elected representatives are like the managers.
But even if you focus on the legitimacy issue, and treat all governments as illegitimate, public places such as roads or squares are still legitimally owned by the people who were coersed into financing them, so you would still be able to apply arbitrary rules to them as long as the legitimate owners agree with them.
Under this illegitimacy model, any arbitrary rule over another person's private property would be seen as coersion or invasion or property, any taxation untied from a voluntarily adquired service would be theft or extortion, and any punishment that is not restitutive in nature or just mere expulsion from another person's private property would be seen as assault, kidnapping or something along these lines.
While no modern governments meet these criterias perfectly, some like Prospera and Liechtenstein get close, and there were some historical governments such as early US that were also close.
Also worth noting is that Argentina right now has a president that believe in the model above, or at least something very close to it, and he is trying to reform the government to minimise the aformentioned individual rights violations.
There are also some notable movements such as the Free State Project that aim to take control over a state democratically, in this case New Hampshire in the US, to also minimise the aformentioned individual rights violations.

Everywhere and nowhere.
There are always rules. If there are no rules, there is no state. Mortal cases are normally handed quite carefully, but there are always excuses.
In this case, the excuse was, that a rocket attack counted as a military operation against an enemy combatant, and not as an execution of the political opponent with his family together.
Other times, there are other excuses. Euthanasia, guys are conspiring against the democracy of the people, society must be cleaned up...
Beside this, the state is by definition of the monopoly of the physical power over a given area. It is also the highest source of law. A state can do it, and they do.
